# If I have a coordinate transform from convention A to B, and a coordinate transform from convention A to C, can I develop a transform from B to C?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working within an existing program with multiple frames of reference (e.g. sensor, local, global, etc), writing an extension that has to perform some new calculations but constrained within the classes currently exposed and the data contained within.

I have access to a change of basis from a global coordinate convention we'll call 'A' to an entity coordinate convention (such as NED - North, East Down) we'll call 'B'.

The entity also has a sensor with it's own basis, we'll call system 'C'. There exists a transform already established from converting a matrix from global coordinate system 'A' to global coordinate system 'C'.

The new processes I have to develop involves repeated conversion from system B to C and back again. Is there a method for developing a transform from two other transforms that are related?

Answer (score 0):

you have

```ts
declare function a2b(l: A): B;
declare function a2c(l: A): C;
```

By your descriptions I imagine the functions are bijective (thus, invertible) you can use your math skills to write

```ts
declare function b2a(l: B): A
```

That convert coordinates in B to A. Then you can define a conversion from B to C as

```ts
function b2c(l: B): C {
  return a2c(b2a(B));
}
```

Comment: I know that one can brute force convert from B to A then A to C, but that's incredibly inefficient. Can one not calculate a B to C conversion from the two?

Comment: Yes, usually you can merge some operations, if the transformation is linear then you can combine as many as you want in a matrix. But to be honest I don't think it will be "incredibly inefficient". At most twice as slow than the conversion you already have.

Comment: Yes, twice as slow, but that penalty is applied each time the transformation happens through out each step (it's a least squares filter), with the filter being applied easily tens of thousands of times across the application of the simulation.

Comment: This is the best answer one can give to your question, it is too vague. You are lucky that the question was not closed, you should at least add [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).